# WSO2 Suspend Scheduled Task

Tags: wso2, scheduled-tasks, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 ESB 4.7 and 4.8.
Is there the possibility to suspend the execution of a running scheduled task?
I need to do it withouth deleting action?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the simple trigger type you can set the count to -1. There should be an equivalent cron pattern, like setting it to a future date that cannot be reached realistically.